# conver a string of lists to a list of lists of lists

Tags: python

I have this string:

```
num="['1', '9', '7', '6'],['2', '0', '8', '3', '7'],['3', '8', '5', '7', '9', '10', '4']"
```

and I want to return/output:

```
[['1', '9', '7', '6'],['2', '0', '8', '3', '7'],['3', '8', '5', '7', '9', '10', '4']]
```

how do i get to this list of lists from that huge string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is a good for exactly that.

```
>>> num="['1', '9', '7', '6'],['2', '0', '8', '3', '7'],['3', '8', '5', '7', '9', '10', '4']"
>>> import ast
>>> list(ast.literal_eval(num))
[['1', '9', '7', '6'], ['2', '0', '8', '3', '7'], ['3', '8', '5', '7', '9', '10', '4']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AST:

```
import ast
num="['1', '9', '7', '6'],['2', '0', '8', '3', '7'],['3', '8', '5', '7', '9', '10', '4']"
num = list(ast.literal_eval(num))
```